# Are there any steps on how to set up an Apache Multi-AZ Amazon RDS database instance and using S3?

Tags: php, drupal, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to set up a Linux/Apache Drupal Website using a Multi-AZ Amazon RDS database instance found in this link:

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/

So far, I have launched the Drupal "Highly Available Web Server with Multi-AZ Amazon RDS database instance and using S3 for storing file content" stack using the link below and it has created my two instances, a Load Balancer and a DB.

I have followed all the steps up until the "Installing and Configuring Drupal" section in the following link thinking that I would just have to run through all the steps for each instance and it would then allow me to view my website on a browser:

http://www.imamuseum.org/cc-mcn09.pdf

My conf file is set up in the ect/httpd/conf.d folder in its own file.

Does anyone have any experience on this?

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks,

Comment: Is something not working? You haven't indicated if anything has gone wrong.

Comment: I am not able to get the site running and would like to know if anyone has ever had any experience with what I am working with. Should these type of questions be on a different forum?

Comment: StackOverflow is primarily for specific questions. "It's not working" is hard for us to help you with. "I'm getting this specific error:" is much easier.